# problems with DESCRIBE statement in oracle sql developer using JDBC driver

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

I just set up a teradata JDBC database through Oracle SQL Developer. I can't get the 'DESCRIBE' command to work, or the 'HELP TABLE' command (usually the case with teradata).

If I put in `DESCRIBE tablename ;` I get error:

> [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.26] [Error 3706] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error: expected something between the beginning of the request and the word 'DESCRIBE'.

If I use `HELP TABLE tablename ;` it gives me a help menu internal to Oracle sql developer

Anyone else have this issue? or know any alternatives to the DESCRIBE command?

Comment: DESCRIBE is an oracle command.  I would not expect it to work with a different database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

SHOW TABLE $database.$table

Comment: Thanks, for some reason SHOW VIEW worked, not SHOW TABLE.

Comment: @ricov07: Well, `SHOW TABLE` is for *tables*, but `SHOW VIEW` is for *views*. `HELP TABLE` also works for views, but most data is NULL, you can use `HELP COLUMN mytable.*` instead.